# Largest (n) numbers with Index and Column name in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, data-analysis

I wish to find out the largest 5 numbers in a DataFrame and store the Index name and Column name for these 5 values.

I am trying to use    nlargest() and idxmax methods but failing to achieve what i want. My code is as below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame
df = DataFrame({'a': [1, 10, 8, 11, -1],'b': [1.0, 2.0, 6, 3.0, 4.0],'c': [1.0, 2.0, 6, 3.0, 4.0]})
```

Can you kindly let me know How can i achieve this. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html):

```
max_vals = df.stack().nlargest(5)
```

This will give you a Series with a multiindex, where the first level is the original DataFrame's index, and the second level is the column name for the given value.  Here's what `max_vals` looks like:

```
3  a    11.0
1  a    10.0
2  a     8.0
   b     6.0
   c     6.0
```

To explicitly get the index and column names, use [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html) on the index of `max_vals`:

```
max_idx = max_vals.index.get_level_values(0)
max_cols = max_vals.index.get_level_values(1)
```

The result of `max_idx`:

```
Int64Index([3, 1, 2, 2, 2], dtype='int64')
```

The result of `max_cols`:

```
Index(['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @root. I learned these methods today and was able to get it. Thanks for your efforts.